# Why does this code fail to compile with Numba?

Tags: python, jit, numba

I have a sample code that illustrates my issue. If you run:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit


@jit(nopython=True)
def test():
    arr = np.array([[[11, 12, 13], [11, 12, 13]], [[21, 22, 23], [21, 22, 23]]])

    arr2 = arr[:, 0, :]

    arr3 = arr2.argsort()

    print(arr3)

test()
```

It will fail with:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of BoundFunction(array.argsort for array(int64, 2d, A)) with parameters ()
During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction(array.argsort for array(int64, 2d, A))
During: typing of call at /home/stark/Work/mmr6/test.py (41)


File "test.py", line 41:
def test():
    <source elided>

    arr3 = arr2.argsort()
    ^
```

argsort is supposed to argsort on the last axis. Essentially it should give me:

```
>>>
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]
```

I thought copying the `arr2` array (with `copy()`) could solve as it would make the array contiguous in memory (instead of a view), but it fails with the same message except that the type of `arr2` in the message is now `array(int64, 2d, C)` as expected.

Why is it failing and how can I fix it?

Comment: **numba is really bad**, I have used it in the past, and half the time it throws errors failing to compile code into C. The reason it fails at line `arr2.argsort()` is because it doesn't understand how to compile numpy into C code.

Comment: My advice would be just don't use numba at all, numpy is already a very optimized library, so there is no need for it anyway.

Comment: numba does not fully support multi-dimensional arrays. Some things work when working with nd-arrays, but a lot of things don't and will complain about "non-contiguous array"

Comment: @Vinzent It doesn't...? I remember using them in the past with `@njit`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq some (a few) things work but a lot of other things don't.

Comment: The example provided could be done without numba.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I recon he wants to use numba to speed it up, however I doubt that it will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sadly a **current known limitation of Numba**. See [this issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4636). Only 1D arrays are supported so far. However, there is a simple workaround in your case:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit


@jit(nopython=True)
def test():
    arr = np.array([[[11, 12, 13], [11, 12, 13]], [[21, 22, 23], [21, 22, 23]]])

    arr2 = arr[:, 0, :]

    arr3 = np.empty(arr2.shape, dtype=arr2.dtype)
    for i in range(arr2.shape[0]):
        arr3[i] = arr2[i, :].argsort()

    print(arr3)

test()
```

Note that even though it is implemented, it will not be faster. See [this issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/6285). Actually, there is no reason Numba could be faster for any given Numpy primitive. However, you can write your own version of Numpy primitives manually with Numba and sometimes get a speed up thanks to algorithmic specialization, parallelism or math optimizations (eg. fast-math). Numba is often great when you want to perform an efficient operation not yet/directly available in Numpy and this operation can be trivially implemented using loops.

Actually, you can use `prange` of Numba and the JIT parameter `parallel=True` to speed up the computation a bit assuming `argsort` is not already running in parallel (AFAIK it should be sequential). This should be a bit faster than the Numpy implementation (which should not run sequentially too) on big arrays (on small arrays, the cost of spawning multiple threads can be bigger than the actual computation).

Comment: Yep, exactly - this was just a canonical example of the issue. In my real code I use numba mostly to take advantage of prange. Thanks a lot, I will do it that way then.